# C# Decorating Console class

Tags: c#, design-patterns, console

I came across an assignment to decorate a Console class (in C#), and implement some custom things inside Write and WriteLine methods.

I had no problem with decorating streams to provide additional functionality, but I have no idea, how to decorate a Console, mostly because of it's static (and have no inheritance, only from System.Object).

So what are the possibilities here?

Thank you!
Lukas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace the streams `Console` writes and reads to using the [`Console.SetOut(TextWriter)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.setout(v=vs.110).aspx), [`Console.SetIn(TextReader)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.setin(v=vs.110).aspx), and [`Console.SetError(TextWriter)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.seterror(v=vs.110).aspx). Just create custom `TextWriter` or `TextReader`  classes that does your decorator behavior and assign them to the static methods.

```
public static void Main()
{
    TextWriter oldOut = Console.Out;
    TextWriter decorator = new MyCustomDecorator(oldOut);
    Console.SetOut(decorator);

    //Do stuff;
}
```